# Copy same element without adding additional code

Tags: html, css

Can you copy same element with same class multiple time on the same page without adding copying same html code.For example i wanna make something like table like i am started on [this picture](http://prntscr.com/dhmm1w).And i don't want my code to look like [THIS](http://prntscr.com/dhmm7r).And also if there is a way,can you select single element after create all of them.Thanks!

Comment: Use a JS loop. Or maybe shadow DOM with custom elements.

Comment: JavaScript is a great place to start to achieve what you want. Have a look [here for a simple example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

Comment: Well i just passed codecademy javascript and im still a newbie but a bit familliar with those loops,but i don't know how to select a given element in CSS when i made them with javascript.Lets say i want to edit 4-th element of 12,how can i select it with CSS :?

Comment: When you are creating your elements, if you want specific parts to behave differently, add an extra class to those elements and update the css accordingly

Comment: if you know the position of an element you can target it with: `:nth-child(X) {/* style*/}`

Comment: Thank for the answer,but what if i want to change image<img> for given element which is into anchor tag.Because i want something like this table: http://prntscr.com/dhmvde.Think it won't work with nth-child selector.Thanks one more time

Comment: idem: `:nth-child(X) childToTarget {/* style*/}` Can't you just ask a clear and clean question with code and your specific issue

Comment: How can you change the <img> content (image and text) with  CSS only?There is a clear question.

Comment: you don't , this is not a css job, is this a new question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a JavaScript `for` loop

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += 
     "<div class='food-group'><a>Link " + i + "</a></div>"; 
  }
</script>
```